# How to get by which provisioning profile was the app built? (developer/ad-hoc/distribution)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm building my app with different provisioning profiles, how can i get the current provisioning profile info into code?

Answer (score 0):

This data is stored in the ipa File.
So unzip the ipa and you will find your embedded.mobileprovision file

To figure out which one it is just open the embedded.mobileprovision file with a text editor

Comment: no,i mean i want to get info from code, not from hte unzip/open :)

Comment: I don't think there is an option to do this.. for this you could use a custom build script which you can pass DEVELOP for example as parameter. Then this could set a DEVELOP flag in the program as well as build the project with the developer profile you specified..